# Solving $3\cos x \cot x + \sin 2x = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How would I solve this trigonometric equation?

$$3\cos x \cot x + \sin 2x = 0$$

I got to this stage: $$3 \cos x = -2 \sin^2x$$

Is is a dead end or is there a easier way solve this equation?

Comment: Try applying the basic trigonometric identity to the right side of the equation.

Comment: You simplified by $\cos x$, which may be $0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have missed $\cos x=0$.

$$3\cos x\cot x+\sin 2x=0$$
$$3\cos x\cdot\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}+2\sin x\cos x=0$$
$$3\cos^2x+2\sin^2x\cos x=0$$
$$\cos x(3\cos x+2\sin^2x)=0$$
$$\cos x(3\cos x+2-2\cos^2x)=0$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x $ then $$-2 \cos^2 x + 3 \cos x + 2 = 0$$

take $y = \cos x$.